# cant seem to figure out how to lock grease pencil animation to a moving camera. 2.8

Tags: camera, grease-pencil

First time posting a question. Forgive my ignorance.

I am really excited about animating in grease pencil with 2.8.  I created a crazy camera move as a test through a few cubes and i wanted to animate a character running with the camera move.

But i've discovered that no matter how i configure the view or origin settings the camera always moves past the grease pencil object. I tried parenting the camera to the grease pencil object and it still doesnt fully move with the camera.

I am pretty new to blender so apologies again if this is a simple fix. I am trying to use it for storyboarding. being able to draw characters in existing camera moves and all that.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use any cam. Preferible [Add-on Camera Rig](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/camera/camera_rigs.html)
2. Create a Grease Pencil
3. Add Object Constrain: Copy Transforms
4. Set: Before Original and place your Grease Pencil in frame.
5. Now you can animate in camera view. GP will follow any mov.

[lock grease pencil to cam](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5c238bbaf93fd45c7ceada8c/1586259033034-2B7O9D7MRFIW3QSY0A2W/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kCS_yISUi_i-xmJ10Y8eLMNZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWQUxwkmyExglNqGp0IvTJZamWLI2zvYWH8K3-s_4yszcp2ryTI0HqTOaaUohrI8PIgvueT39bIXjt2evYMKV6P4HQU7HUOtrSc--21-aCqfY/copytransformslow.gif?format=750w)